# Download a Free App published only to India AppStore while my primary iTunes account is US Appstore?

Tags: itunes, applications, ios-appstore

Download a Free App published only to India AppStore while my primary iTunes account is US Appstore?

I have years (maybe a decade) with my iTunes account on US Appstore. I do not wish to switch permanently as I have Apps bought from it.

I just need a few 'Free' India AppStore apps now and then for when I visit.

**Is there some temporary way to switch or buy them?**

**Some kind of workaround?**
e.g. Maybe create an alternate user account and as a family member on India AppStore?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple accounts, you just have to log in and out to switch between them.

After you created an India account, log out of your US account:

- Settings -> App and iTunes Stores -> Apple ID -> Sign Out

Then sign in with your India account. Swipe close your AppStore app, then go into it again. Now you can download apps from your India account.

Comment: I only wish to switch temporarily for few apps while I visit India, and wish to switch back to US store immediately without losing any of my US store stuff. Is this doable without issues?

Comment: Well yes, have you tried the above?

Comment: I was afraid I will lose my US store & US store apps on the iPhone so I wanted to be sure before I tried it. Can I switch right back or is there a waiting period/ i.e. you can also switch stores certain times in X weeks etc?

Comment: Last time I did it it worked perfectly :) no waiting period